# Deal with Jenkins password encryption when stored in a SCM

Tags: encryption, version-control, jenkins

I'm currently storing the Jenkins home directory in a Git repository.

The Jenkins configuration has been initialized on a machine A: security settings (authenticated LDAP), global settings, SCM crendentials, etc...

When this Jenkins home is cloned from the Git repository on a machine B, all passwords are encrypted. And unfortunately the Jenkins master that is running on machine B can't read these encrypted passwords.

Moreover, as soon as the configuration is saved, all passwords get re-encrypted, so it seems useless to edit the configuration files manually and put passwords in plain text.

Does anyone has any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! Here is the result of my research.

My initial `JENKINS_HOME/.gitignore` file was as follows:

```
# Miscellaneous Jenkins litter
*.log
*.tmp
*.old
*.json

# Generated Jenkins state
/.owner
/queue.xml
/fingerprints/
/shelvedProjects/
/updates/
/logs/

# Credentials
/secrets/
secret.key

# Job state
builds/
workspace/
modules/
lastStable
lastSuccessful
nextBuildNumber
```

But, taken from http://xn--thibaud-dya.fr/jenkins_credentials.html, Jenkins uses a `JENKINS_HOME/secrets/master.key` to encrypt all passwords, whether in the global settings or in SCM crendentials.
This made me think that the same `master.key` file was used to decrypt passwords.

So I've tried to remove all credential-related entries from the `.gitignore` file, thus allowing to push them in my Git repo and then pull them on the machine B (another brand new Jenkins master) and... it works well! All passwords are stored encrypted and since all masters share the same `master.key` file, all passwords can be decrypted.

Hope it can help someone else!